# Why can't I center the icons within their borders?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add social media icons to my website, but I'm having trouble centering them in their bordered box:

[image: icons aren't centered]

This is my HTML:

```
     <div id="social">

        <a class="social-button" href="#">
            <img src="/resources/img/coolicon-1.svg">
        </a>

        <a class="social-button" href="#">
            <img src="/resources/img/coolicon.svg">
        </a>

        <a class="social-button" href="#">
            <img src="/resources/img/coolicon-2.svg">
        </a>

    </div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
* {
    background-color: black;
}

.social-button {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

I double checked and the SVGs don't have any extra padding:

[image: the SVGs I'm using]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` elements use `display: inline;` as default, so you need to make them `display: inline-block;` for making images inside the boxes

```css
* {
  background-color: black;
}

.social-button {
  display: inline-block; /* Added the display here */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  padding: 2px;
}
   
.social-button > img {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="social">
  <a class="social-button" href="#">
    <img width="40px" height="40px" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/sco/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/1200px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" />
  </a>

  <a class="social-button" href="#">
    <img width="40px" height="40px" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/sco/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/1200px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" />
  </a>

  <a class="social-button" href="#">
    <img width="40px" height="40px" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/sco/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/1200px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked to set the box properly around the icons, but the icons are still not vertically centered: there is more space at the bottom than at the top

Comment: @krimo33 could you check my modified answer? I put `display: flex;` for all images that would help to place them in center

Comment: It worked, thank you! And I think with the added `display: flex;` there is no longer a need for the `display: inline-block;`. It works just fine without

Answer (score 0):

```css
*,*::before,*::after{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background-color: black;
}

.social-button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="social">
  <a class="social-button" href="#">
    <img width="40px" height="40px" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/sco/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/1200px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" />
  </a>

  <a class="social-button" href="#">
    <img width="40px" height="40px" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/sco/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/1200px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" />
  </a>

  <a class="social-button" href="#">
    <img width="40px" height="40px" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/sco/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/1200px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" />
  </a>
</div>
```